# Visual Studio Remove "Run On" Database References

Tags: visual-studio-2005, usability

In Visual Studio, when I create a new script containing a stored procedure, my usual course to run it on our databases is to right click and select "Run On".  In the database references window, I add/select what I need and run.  We've just switched database servers in our development environment and a number of the references here are no longer valid.  Does anyone know how to remove them from this list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the references in the project you will see the old database references.  Remove them from there, also you need to remove them from your server explorer.